# It does not insert my data on create eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

My User::create() function does not work whenever I insert the $fillable variable in the model User,

here is my **User model**

```
Class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $table    = 'vcs_users';
    protected $guarded = [ 'id', 'password' ];
    protected $hidden  = [ 'password', 'remember_token' ];
    protected $fillable = [ 'key_code', 'password'];

  }
```

whenever I remove the $fillable variable in the User model, the insert works but when I return it, It does not insert anymore. I also do not want to remove the $fillable variable because I have some functions too where I need to update the keycode and password.

**UserRegisterController**

```
User::create( $data );
```

this is my code for update

```
$new_password = array(
'password' => Hash::make( $x[ 'password' ] ),
'key_code' => ''
);
User::where( 'email', 'some_email' )->update( $new_password );
```

Comment: Use either `guarded` or `fillable` as they are blacklist and whitelist for mass assignement. Using both doesn't make sense and may cause errors.

Comment: what could be an alternative solution for that.. if i remove the $fillable var.. the update password does not work

Comment: What do you mean exactly by not working?

Comment: It does not update the password and keycode column whenever I remove the fillable variable.. but when i return it, it works

Comment: You have set `password` as both guarded and fillable, so when you get rid of `fillable`, it is guarded and can't be mass assigned. This is the only problem here. So simply remove it from the `guarded` array and it will work.

Comment: still not working.. it still not inserting

Comment: Then show your current model code as well as the controller method (all of the code)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change `User::where( 'email', 'some_email' )->update( $new_password );` to `User::where( 'email', 'some_email' )->get()->update( $new_password );`